# Como ignorar um error usando Json.NET sem danificar o que já foi lido

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Existe alguma forma de continuar a "deserealização" de um objeto, usando [Json.NET](http://json.net/), mesmo quando uma propriedade esta corrompida e sem danificar o que já foi "lido"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível através da utilização de um [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm). A classe `JsonConverter` converte um objeto em JSON e vice versa, mas esse processo pode ser customizado se você criar uma classe que derive dela e sobrescrever os métodos [`JsonConverter.ReadJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) e/ou [`JsonConverter.WriteJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm).

A documentação oficial do Json.NET possui um exemplo muito simples de como um *custom JsonConverter* pode ser implementado. [Aqui o link do exemplo.](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Note que você também pode especificar um `JsonConverter` para ser utilizado como padrão durante o processo de "serialização" e "deserialização" de um objeto através do atributo [`JsonConverterAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm), isso pode ser útil para acelerar o desenvolvimento.

Recomendo também que você de uma olhada no exemplo da [resposta dessa pergunta no Stack Overflow (Inglês) *Using Json.NET converters to deserialize properties*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031283/1324082). Ela pode lhe ser muito útil como ponta pé inicial para desenvolver o seu *custom JsonConverter*.

Comment: Acho que faltou detalhar melhor, na verdade eu não conheço o objeto que será deserializado, será dinâmico. Antes de eu me aprofundar no JsonConvert, vc poderia dizer se isso é possível com ele?

Comment: Sim, é totalmente possível, o JsonConveter lhe permite ter total controle sobre a serialização e deserialização, recomendei ele justamente por voce ter falado que uma propriedade poderia estar corrompida, assim você poderia tratar essa propriedade durante o processo.