# Databinding para objetos JSON.NET: como implementar?

Tags: json, winforms, vb.net, datagridview

Minha aplicação lida muito com HTTP requests que retornam dados JSON. Eu uso a biblioteca JSON.NET para manipulá-los. Eis um exemplo simulado e bastante resumido da informação (há redundâncias nos dados originais, que não posso postar por serem informações sensíveis):

```
    [{
    "id": 1,
    "conta_movimento_id": 726,
    "conta_movimento": {
        "id": 726,
        "nome": "FULANO DE TAL - CONTA 2"
    },
    "especie_id": 1,
    "especie": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "PAGAMENTO"
    },
    "favorecido_id": 34,
    "favorecido": {
        "id": 34,
        "nome": "FULANO DE TAL",
        "contas": [{
            "id": 724,
            "nome": "FULANO DE TAL - CONTA 1"
        }, {
            "id": 726,
            "nome": "FULANO DE TAL - CONTA 2"
        }]
    },
    "valor": 1564.23
    }, {
    "id": 2,
    "conta_movimento_id": 725,
    "conta_movimento": {
        "id": 725,
        "nome": "SICRANO DE TAL - CONTA 1"
    },
    "especie_id": 1,
    "especie": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "PAGAMENTO"
    },
    "favorecido_id": 35,
    "favorecido": {
        "id": 35,
        "nome": "SICRANO DE TAL",
        "contas": [{
            "id": 725,
            "nome": "FULANO DE TAL - CONTA 1"
        }]
    },
    "valor": 2323.79
    }]
```

Preciso que esses dados sejam exibidos em controles Winforms que usam Databinding (principalmente `ComboBox` e `DataGridView`). Não pretendo editar dados nesse momento, só precisava exibi-los de forma amigável para o usuário.

Escrevi uma rotina improvisada que converte `IEnumerable(Of JToken)` para `DataTable`:

```
Module JsonAsDataTable
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> Public Function ToDataTable(ByVal jtokens As IEnumerable(Of JToken), Optional ByVal trim_object_columns As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal castToCLRtypes As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal orderBy As String = Nothing) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable, sdt As DataTable, dr, sdr As DataRow, dateproperty As Date
        If jtokens IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each jt In jtokens
                dr = dt.NewRow
                For Each jp In jt.Children(Of JProperty)
                    sdt = Nothing
                    If Not dt.Columns.Contains(jp.Name) Then dt.Columns.Add(jp.Name, IIf(castToCLRtypes, GetType(Object), GetType(JToken)))
                    If jp.Value.Type = JTokenType.Object AndAlso jp.Value.Children.Count = 1 AndAlso jp.Value.First.Type = JTokenType.Property AndAlso DirectCast(jp.Value.First, JProperty).Name = "date" Then
                        If Date.TryParse(DirectCast(jp.Value.First, JProperty).Value, dateproperty) Then
                            dr.SetField(jp.Name, New JValue(dateproperty))
                        Else
                            dr.SetField(jp.Name, JValue.CreateNull)
                        End If
                    Else
                        dr.SetField(jp.Name, jp.Value)
                        If jp.Value.Type = JTokenType.Object Then
                            sdt = AsDataTable({jp.Value}, trim_object_columns)
                        ElseIf jp.Value.Type = JTokenType.Array Then
                            sdt = AsDataTable(jp.Value, trim_object_columns)
                        End If
                        If sdt IsNot Nothing Then
                            sdr = sdt.Select.FirstOrDefault
                            For Each sdc As DataColumn In sdt.Columns
                                If Not dt.Columns.Contains(jp.Name & "." & sdc.ColumnName) Then dt.Columns.Add(jp.Name & "." & sdc.ColumnName, GetType(Object))
                                If sdr IsNot Nothing Then dr.SetField(jp.Name & "." & sdc.ColumnName, sdr(sdc.ColumnName))
                            Next
                            If trim_object_columns Then dt.Columns.Remove(jp.Name)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Next
            If castToCLRtypes Then
                For Each drow In dt.Select
                    For Each dcol As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                        If TypeOf drow(dcol) Is JToken Then drow(dcol) = ToField(drow(dcol))
                    Next
                Next
            End If
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy) Then
                dt = dt.Select("", orderBy).CopyToDataTable
            End If
        End If
        Return dt
    End Function
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> Friend Function ToField(token As JToken) As Object
        If token Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Select Case token.Type
            Case JTokenType.Boolean
                Return token.Value(Of Boolean)
            Case JTokenType.Bytes
                Return token.Value(Of Byte())
            Case JTokenType.Date
                Return token.Value(Of Date)
            Case JTokenType.Float
                Return token.Value(Of Double)
            Case JTokenType.Guid
                Return token.Value(Of Guid)
            Case JTokenType.Integer
                Return token.Value(Of Integer)
            Case JTokenType.Null
                Return Nothing
            Case JTokenType.Property
                Return ExtractObjectFrom(CType(token, JProperty).Value)
            Case JTokenType.String
                Return token.Value(Of String)
            Case JTokenType.TimeSpan
                Return token.Value(Of TimeSpan)
            Case JTokenType.Uri
                Return token.Value(Of Uri)
            Case Else
                Return token.ToString
        End Select
    End Function
End Module
```

Agora eu estou ciente de que minha solução não é nem limpa nem confiável. É apenas a primeira coisa em que pensei para exibir os itens em um  `DataGridView` de uma maneira que o usuário pudesse classificar os dados clicando nos cabeçalhos das colunas, o que um simples Array de JToken não permitiria. Meu DataGridView deve ficar assim:

<kbd>**Conta-------------------------**</kbd><kbd>**Movimento-**</kbd><kbd>**Valor--------**</kbd><kbd>**Favorecido-----**</kbd>
<kbd>FULANO DE TAL - CONTA 2</kbd><kbd>PAGAMENTO</kbd><kbd>R$ 1.564,23</kbd><kbd>FULANO DE TAL</kbd>
<kbd>SICRANO DE TAL - CONTA 1</kbd><kbd>PAGAMENTO</kbd><kbd>R$ 2.323,79</kbd><kbd>SICRANO DE TAL</kbd>

Este é um exemplo bem simples. Há casos em que cada item do JSON tem propriedades que também são objectos complexos, então eu uso dois DataGridView, sendo que o segundo é repovoado a cada vez que uma nova linha é selecionada no primeiro. Tudo baseado na conversão de JToken() em DataTable com base no código acima.

Não obstante, eu gostaria de escrever uma classe custom que embrulhasse os objetos JToken, e talvez uma classe Collection para listá-los de modo que o `DataGridView` entendesse e manipulasse com facilidade, ativando recursos tais como classificação (isto é essencial para mim) e filtragem (isto seria um prêmio extra se eu conseguisse).

Minha questão é: *qual o **conjunto mínimo de Interfaces** que tais classes deveriam implementar para realizar isso?*

Comment: A sua pergunta é boa, mas, muito ampla, poderia focar em um `JSON` com um exemplo `JSON` e como deseja exibir na `DataGridView` ou `Dropdownlist`. Usando `JSON.NET` que é a biblioteca que é a mais utilizada no mundo `.NET` o processo fica muito fácil com modelos de classe. Não vejo motivo para Reflexão se a classe `JSON.NET` for bem utilizada. Em relação a classificação e ordenação são outros passos após a disponibilidade da informação. Tem como fazer um [exemplo minimo e testavel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Obrigado. Fiz edições para acrescentar mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o seu problema não é muito pontual, me parece que possui diversos arquivos `JSON`, vou propor, então, na sua última edição referente ao `JSON` inserido na pergunta. A forma usual de trabalhar com isso seria criar os modelos de `classes` e utilizar a biblioteca [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/8.0.3) para converter num objeto de classe.

> ***Modelos:***

`Base`

```
Public MustInherit Class Base
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")>
    Public Property Id As Integer

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("nome")>
    Public Property Nome As String
End Class
```

---

`Especie`

```
Public Class Especie
    Inherits Base
End Class
```

---

`ContaMovimento`

```
Public Class ContaMovimento
    Inherits Base
End Class
```

---

`Contas`

```
Public Class Contas
    Inherits Base
End Class
```

---

`Favorecido`

```
Public Class Favorecido
    Inherits Base
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("contas")>
    Public Property Contas As List(Of Contas)
End Class
```

---

`Conta`

```
Public Class Conta
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")>
    Public Property Id As Integer

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("conta_movimento_id")>
    Public Property ContaMovimentoId As Integer

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("conta_movimento")>
    Public Property ContaMovimento As ContaMovimento

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("especie_id")>
    Public Property EspecieId As Integer

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("especie")>
    Public Property Especie As Especie

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("favorecido_id")>
    Public Property FavorecidoId As Integer

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("favorecido")>
    Public Property Favorecido As Favorecido

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("valor")>
    Public Property Valor As Decimal
End Class
```

<sub>***Observação:*** todas essas classes foram decoradas para saber qual item do `JSON` ele tem que deserializar (`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty`)</sub>

---

> ***Como utilizar:***

```
Dim json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("arquivo.json")
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Conta))(json)
```

sendo que na variável `result` tem o resultado de um `array` de `Conta` com todas as informações do `JSON` organizadas e de fácil manipulação.

---

Para carregar isso dentro de um `DataGridView` é simples a partir do momento do carregamento dessa classe.

`Form - Code`

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("arquivo.json")
        Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Conta))(json)
        DataGridView1.DataSource =
            (From items In result
             Select New With {
                 .Conta = items.ContaMovimento.Nome,
                 .Movimento = items.Especie.Nome,
                 items.Valor,
                 .Favorecido = items.Favorecido.Nome
                 }).ToList()

    End Sub
End Class
```

***Resultado em tela:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é um exemplo e tem o que precisa, porque, o `JSON` ofereceu lista de itens, um objeto de um item e fica fácil com base nesse partir para os outros.

Mais alguns links que podem ser usados como tutorial:

- [Como ler uma struct dentro de outra com Json.Net?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155617/como-ler-uma-struct-dentro-de-outra-com-json-net)
- [Deserializar Array JSon em um Array de Objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110771/deserializar-array-json-em-um-array-de-objetos)
- [Como ignorar um error usando Json.NET sem danificar o que já foi lido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110073/como-ignorar-um-error-usando-json-net-sem-danificar-o-que-j%C3%A1-foi-lido)
- [Como converter uma resposta em JSON para um objeto em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/706/como-converter-uma-resposta-em-json-para-um-objeto-em-c/707#707)

Comment: +1 e aceito como resposta, pois resolve o problema proposto. Não obstante, abstraindo a origem dos dados (neste caso, JSON), agradeço caso os colegas possam me instruir sobre como tornar uma dada classe qualquer apta a fornecer itens classificáveis e filtráveis para um DataSource... Grato!

Comment: @VBobCat faltou classificação e pequisa?

Comment: Não, não faltou nada. Eu apenas estava pensando em uma classe hipotética que recolhe dados a partir de uma lógica interna qualquer, e tem uma única propriedade pública default, `Default Property Item(byval key as String) as Object`. Imagine que eu tenha um grupo de instâncias dessa classe, e queira fornecê-lo como DataSource de um DataGridView, e depois definir manualmente as colunas do DataGridView indicando como .DataProperyName de cada uma delas o string que a classe vai interpretar e devolver o dado necessário. Não sei se devo fazer outra pergunta, nem se essa pergunta seria ampla demais.

Comment: Faça outra pergunta @VBobCat, e em vez de colocar o problema em um todo faça igual a essa, coloque um problema pontual ai fica fácil dar possibilidades de solução.